# Not able to insert values into Database using oop concept in php

Tags: php, database, authentication, insert

**dbclass.php**

```
   <?php  
class DB{
    public static function connect(){
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","yash","sample"); 
        return $conn;
    }
}
$dbb = new DB;
$dbb->connect();
?>
```

**classone.php**

```
<?php 
include('dbclass.php');
class Books {
    private  $title;
    private  $price;
    private  $conn;
    function __construct($title,$price){
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->price = $price;
    }
    function getDetails(){
        echo $this->title."</br>";
        echo $this->price;
    }
    public function insertbook(){
        $conn = DB::connect();
        $q1 = "INSERT INTO sbook (title,price) VALUES ($this->title,$this->price)";
        $run = mysqli_query($conn,$q1);
    }

}
$physics =  new Books("physics",20);
$physics->getDetails();
$physics->insertbook();
?>
```

Even after passing the `$conn` variable in `mysqli_query`, I'm not able to insert values in the database. 
Cannot able to figure out, what's happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: And __prepared statements__

Comment: I've checked it, print_r($run) gives me nothing but print_r($q1) gives me the exact query which is correct.

Comment: Do you need `$dbb = new DB; $dbb->connect();` in the db class?

Answer (score 1):

You should have to prepare your SQL query with quotes as below

```
$q1 = "INSERT INTO sbook (title,price) VALUES ('$this->title','$this->price')";
```

Also you should use your private class member `$conn` as `$this->conn`.

```
$this->conn = DB::connect();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! :), but as $this->title gives me the value exactly, then like what's the point of using '  ' here?

Comment: It's not working when we use  $this->conn = DB::connect() FYI.

Comment: you also need to update the same in your `mysqli_query` as `$run = mysqli_query($this->conn,$q1);`